# Searching through a matrix with Ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
0 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
```

How can I define a matrix in Ruby, and then search through it?

I would like to write a program which searches through all rows and returns rows with the highest sum of "1".

Comment: and what have you tried?   Do you know how to write this code in other languages?

Comment: Unfortunately not, ruby is the first language that I've started to learn.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html

Comment: so as I understand the simplest matrix will be `a = [[1,0],[0,1]]`, what about searching through it?

Comment: There is a built-in matrix class for ruby

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We appreciate that this is your first foray into Ruby, or a language, however, this question doesn't suit the purposes of Stack Overflow. We expect that you will have tried to write code, that something was baffling you, and you need help getting the code to work. Your question is only asking for code, which is not what we do; We're not a "write code for me that does something" kind of place. Please read through some tutorials, try writing your code, and if you run into problems making it work feel free to ask a specific question about that.

Comment: Mr. the Tin Man. Thank you for advice. I understand what I have done wrong. First time I have encountered situation in which I have no idea how to write a single line of code because of my lacking knowledge about matrices. Please don't get me wrong I wasn't looking for ready code. I only wanted to ask for basic examples of creation and searching through matrix. I gave program description in question because I haven't found anything helpful on others questions about matrices, so I thought that it will help to describe what problems I have encountered. My apologies for this inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick way to define a matrix in Ruby:

```
Array.new 6, Array.new(6, 0)
# => [
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
     ]
```

The above code initializes an array with 6 items and defaults their values to the 2nd argument which is another array with 6 items and default values of 0.

In other more imperative languages you would use nested loops:

```
matrix = []
for x in [0,1,2,3,4,5]
  for y in [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    matrix[x] ||= [] # create the row as an empty array
    matrix[x] << y # push the y value to it
  end
end
# matrix is now:
# => [ 
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     ]
```

To search through the matrix and find the row with greatest sum:

```
greatest_sum_row_index = 0
greatest_sum = 0

matrix.each_with_index do |row, i|
  # row.inject(:+) is a shortcut to adding each int in the array and returning the sum
  sum = row.inject(:+)
  if sum > greatest_sum
    greatest_sum = sum
    greatest_sum_row_index = i
  end
end

# highest_row is now the index of the greatest sum row
matrix[greatest_sum_row_index] # returns the row with the greatest sum
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer. What can I do in case when I only want to check amount of `1` in each row of matrix and then return all rows with greatest amount?

Comment: if there are only 0s and 1s then the sum of the entire row would give you exactly that, the number of 1s in it. Math.

Comment: I agree, according to my example it would work out, but if given matrix contains also other values than 0s and 1s how can I check amount of certain value? because inject would not work out in that case.

Comment: you can select values out of the array (row) and add those together: 
`row.select { |i| i == 1 }.size` that will select all the 1s, return a new array of just 1s, and then `.size` will tell you how many there are.

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thank you great explanation with examples.

Comment: @Gregy I would implement the second part as `matrix.group_by{|a| a.reduce(:+)}.max_by{|k,_| k}.pop` This way if multiple rows have the same reduction you will get all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If the array were large and memory requirements were a concern, you might do something like this:

```
def rows_with_most_ones(arr)
  arr.each_with_index.with_object([-1, nil]) do |(row,i),best|
    tot = row.count(1)
    case tot<=>best.first
    when 1 then best.replace([tot, [i]])
    when 0 then best.last << i
    end
  end
end

arr = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

rows_with_most_ones(arr)
  #=> [3, [1, 3, 4]]
```